# Ansible - Returning variable from role/tasks back to the playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

**I have a playbook with below format:**

```
- name: Get VM IP
 hosts: local
 connection: local
 gather_facts: true
 roles:
   - operations/get_IP
```

**In my Role/tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: GET IP.
  script: " Script to get the IP"
  register: IP_status
```

I want to return the variable 'IP_status' back to my playbook. What is the right way to do it?
I want to return this variable as I want to create a JSON object by parsing the value especially in case of errors.

Answer (score 5):

That variable is already "available" to your playbook as a hostvar. You can access it directly as long as the role has already run:

```
- name: Get VM IP
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true

  roles:
    - operations/get_IP

  post_tasks:
    - debug:
        var: IP_status.stdout
```

Comment: If you call the role twice the 2nd replaces the 1st value ?